# How to define a function in javascript, when using jQuery, to not break other js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code that works in a WordPress theme. When I try to add my own function, not a jQuery plugin but it could be, it breaks javascript in the plugin [Every Calendar +1](http://andrewbevitt.com/code/everycalplus1/).  The calendar does not render.

my own function is

```
var get_px_int = function(px_string) {
            px_string.replace('/[a-zA-Z]/', '');
            px_string = parseInt(px_string);
            return px_string;
        }
```

and I'm trying to use it in this way

```
$('#branding').css({
  "min-height" : $("#header-slideshow li").height()
                 + get_px_int($("#header-slideshow").css('margin-top'))
                 + get_px_int($("#header-slideshow li").css('font-size'))*5
});
```

I need a min-height based on other heights of elements but the height() returns 'px' and I need to get rid of the text and cast it as an integer to use in the equation to compute the min-height.
All of this works the way it should. But just the declaration of the function and not even calling it, breaks the plugin javascript. I know I need to instantiate the function in a way that is like a prototype or class or something.  I've tried the function as a plugin, as an object, all of my code is wrapped in ( foo = function() {} ); foo();
I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: What error message or undesired behavior are you getting?

Comment: I doubt this is the source of the specific problem you're asking about, but -- `replace` does not work the way you think it does.

Comment: On the Calendar page, it continues to say "Loading..." and the calendar never displays.

Comment: Have you investigated it using diagnostic tools (firebug, etc.)?

Comment: @ruakh, Thank you. I changed it to `px_string = px_string.replace(/[a-zA-Z]*/, '');` but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your JS console?

Comment: @JonathanM I am more of a backend dev and have recently dove into jQuery. My experience with javascript is from 6 years ago. So I use Firebug regularly, but don't know what I would do for JS.

Comment: Your posted code is fine. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2NgNR/5/

Comment: @AlexWayne Error Console says "px_string" undefined. So how do I pass and get that variable?

Comment: So `px_string` is undefined because your are passing in `undefined`. Are you sure that your jQuery `css()` calls return a value? Check them, what do you get? `console.log($("#header-slideshow").css('margin-top'))`

Comment: Can you post the HTML for `header-slideshow`?

Comment: @JonathanM @AlexWayne So, I don't get that error when loading a page that does not contain the calendar, but do get the error on the calendar page. The jsfiddle seems to confirm that the error is not how I am accepting the value in the function, so it is probably the variable getting passed is undefined. Which would mean `$("#header-slideshow").css('margin-top')` or `$("#header-slideshow li").css('font-size')`

Comment: I tried commenting out the replace line and it works!
But I am still confused. Why would that line of code throw of other javascript code in it's own file and namespace?!

Comment: I wrapped the specific code to that element with `if($('#header-slideshow').length > 0) { }`.  The slideshow is not on the page yet but I thought the html wrap was. So that explains the undefined. And trying to deal with undefined within `.replace()` causes errors elsewhere. So the solution turned out to not even be the answer to the question. But thank you for all of your assistance and @ruakh, if you did not let on to the `.replace()` issues, I may have never figured it out. I was using it like PHP in a way.

Answer (score 1):

`.replace(...)` is unnecessary as `partInt()` discards trailing non-numeric characters, and there should be no leading non-numeric characters.

Try :

```
var get_px_int = function(px_string) {
    return parseInt(px_string || 0) || 0;
};
```

Thus,

- if `px_string` is undefined (which is falsy), `parseInt()` will return zero.
- if `parseInt()` returns `NaN` (which is falsy), the function will return zero.

You can easily change the default value to anything you like.